# How do I install locales-all on 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, locale

For some reason the latest Ubuntu has no package for `locales-all`. Before I reinstalled my local development environment this worked flawlessly and I can't seem to find an alternative package for this.

```
sudo apt-get install locales-all
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package locales-all is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'locales-all' has no installation candidate
```

How would I go about to install all locales?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [ubuntu packages website](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/locales-all), `locales-all` should be present in 18.04.

Have you checked if you have the **universe** repository enabled?

Check [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) for a couple of examples on how to enable it.

Comment: Thank you. I never thought of it since universe have always been enabled by default. Enabling universe solved the issue!